# How to store response in a variable in Volley?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I Want to Store the response of Volley in a Public variable but  when I Toast it out the volley request that returns null

```
public  JSONArray array ;
String URL = "http://192.168.1.104/json.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);

        array = new JSONArray();

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest( URL,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

               try {
                    array = response;
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);

Toast.makeText(json.this, array.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: `onResponse` will be called asynchronous. This means that you can;t use `array` before it is called.

Comment: You need to look into how callbacks work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people have said, calling the Toast initiation within onResponse() works, but the *best* way to handle this is to create a small listener interface or method that is called in onResponse and implemented where you need it.

I'd  also strongly suggest only passing the data you *need* and saving that in a model class, rather than just saving the response outright.

a very simple example would be

```java
String URL = "http://192.168.1.104/json.php";

   // make sure your class implements this
   public  interface ResponseListener {
      public gotResponse(JSONArray array);
   }

   // implementation of ResponseListener
   public gotResponse(JSONArray array) {
      // eventually do more with this data
      Toast.makeText(json.this, array.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_json);

        ResponseListener listener = this;

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest( URL,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

               try {
                    listener.gotResponse(response);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be moving the line:

```
Toast.makeText(json.this, array.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

exactly to the line after: `array = response;`